# I'm unable to to put my nickname

Tags: pokemon-go

I m not able to choose a nickname for me in the game so which type of nickname I should try?

Comment: Try Letters and numbers (A-Z,a-z,0-9, not e.g.: Ö,Ä,Ü,é,Ì...)

Comment: Please expand your question to include more details, such as which type of device you're using, which type of account you have and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that the nickname is already taken? Your nickname has to be unique.